# Ubuntu не запускается застревая с надписью BusyBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu

На ноутбуке Ubuntu без явных причин перестало загружаться. Останавливаясь с надписью BusyBox.

Популярные советы вроде использования  fsck оказались бесполезны.

Также до возникновения проблемы делал резервные копии, создавал образ диска акронисом. При восстановлении из образов, сделанных в разное время, в том числе на другой физический диск, в том числе в виртуальную машину, проблема остаётся - система не загружается застревая с надписью  BusyBox и т.д.

```
BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Подозрение что каким-то образом переименовываются пути разделов. Которые /dev/sdb1 и т.д. не знаю как это проверить.

Comment: На самом деле система загрузилась. То, что вы видите и есть чистый Linux. Не загрузилось пользовательское окружение. Проблема может быть в initramfs или в системе инициализации. Посмотрите вывод `dmesg`, есть ли там сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: По dmesg много строк, но чего-то с ошибками не видно

Comment: Еще есть вариант с неправильными настройками grub'а (или какой там сейчас загрузчик), может быть указан не тот initramfs, неправильный путь к /boot/ или не тот GUID винчестера

Comment: Приведите ещё штук 20 сообщений которые выводятся перед BusyBox v1.18.5... обычно там там указывается причина остановки загрузки пользовательского окружения и запуск BusyBox.
Переименование /dev/sdb1 вполне возможно. оссобенно когда в системе несколько дисков и разной скорости. чтобы избежать проблем используйте в /etc/fstab UUID= , вместо /dev/sd*